# Riak.js how to get keys with getAll

Tags: node.js, riak

I'm currently using riak.js as a client for a riak database, do any of you know how to retrieve the keys along with all the results?

current query im using is 
    `db.getAll('scores');`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A key listing in Riak will return the key only. In order to get the data, you will need to retrieve the objects individually through GET requests.

A key listing in Riak is a very expensive operation, and while quite useful in small development and testing environments [it is not recommended that you use it in larger production environments](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/references/http/list-keys/) as it will affect the performance of the cluster and not scale well.